# Read the Permissions used by an Application in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

How can we read programatically the set of permissions being used by an Application in Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read `WMAppManifest.xml` file

```
private static void Read()
{
  string ret = string.Empty;

  try
  {
    XElement xe = XElement.Load("WMAppManifest.xml");
    //look for Capabilities section here
  }
  catch
  {
    // Ignore errors in case this method is called
    // from design time in VS.NET
  }
}
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2011/01/04/get-application-title-from-windows-phone.aspx

Comment: Thank you Anton. Can I read Manifest file of other application apart from my application?

Comment: No, you can't do that. Every application is located in it's own sandbox. And each app has an access to it's own sandbox only.